# How to provide additional data when cancelling using CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, windows

CancellationToken can be used to cancel a task in many ways. However, my application needs more information than just the task being canceled. For example, it needs to know who canceled the task, when the task was canceled, and why it was canceled. Is there any way to provide additional data when cancelling a task?

Comment: Create your own derived structure that records additional information and pass the "CancellationTokenWithExtraInformation" around.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
private static void Work(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
   while (true)
   {
      if(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        return ("999999999");
      }
     Console.Write("345");
   }
}
```

The key is in what is returned the cancellation token only tells you when to quit...